# Python write() adding spaces in between lines

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a script with Flask on Python 3. I have a server that asks for input that will usually be multiple lines. I then take that input and write it to a file:

```
@app.route('/editor',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    result = request.form
    print(request)
    global file
    file = result['script']
    f = open(file, "r+")
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()

    return render_template("result.html",result = result, file = file, cont = contents)
```

In this code^, I get a file name from an input form and then use a Flask template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>File Editor</title>
   <body>
      Editor:
      <form action = "http://192.168.#.###:5000/save" method = "POST" id="form">
      <textarea name="script" form="form" rows="10" cols="100">{{cont}}</textarea>
      <p><input type = "submit" value = "Save" /></p>
   </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

This^ redirects to the save path

```
@app.route('/save',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def save():
    contents = request.form
    contents = contents.items()
    ope = open(file, 'w+')
    i = ''
    for key, value in contents:
        i = value
    print(i)
    i.replace('\n', '')
    ope.write(i)
    ope.close()
    return redirect("/", code=302)
```

But when I open the file that it edited, there are waay more lines than there are supposed to be(it adds blank line in between). If there is one line between two words it makes it 3, if there are 2 lines it makes it 5, if there are no lines it makes it one. Any ideas why?

Comment: are you sure that the `i` value doesn't contain any spaces in that? Not just new lines `\n`

Comment: Replace will not change the value of `i`, you need to assign the result `i = i.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: @Patricio this is it, along with possibly a mismatch between crlf / lf line endings. Strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem @Patricio, it works now!